# Where should I write common javascript code related to controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, coding-style

I am in a situation to write some client side validation. For example, in a page I use a `Repeater` control which creates a list of item. There we could select number of items using a check box (in the first column). So if I click 'Delete' button, the selected cases will be deleted. So I need to check if the selected item's count is zero or not. So my question is, where should I write this kind of validations ? In a common .js file or in the page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done in a separate file. You will encounter times when you will need to have the id of the control being validated for one reason or another so you should provide a manner within that file to receive those ids (parameter name in a function, global variable (not recommended), custom namespace object).

Comment: So for all `Repeaters` in my project, should I use same `ID` . Or pass the `ID` of the repeater and traverse through it  ?

Comment: @Rauf: No, I would say you need to make your javascript capable of accepting an id for any control or set of controls that you might pass to it. You wouldn't pass the id of the repeater because that's not what gets validated, but you may need to pass the generated control fields (textboxes, checkboxes, radios, etc).

Comment: Is it a good idea to decorate the controls(textboxes, checkboxes, radios, etc) with a class name and use jQuery to loop through the class items ?

Comment: @Rauf: If you're using jQuery that's not a bad idea. It's one of the tricks I use. I haven't seen anywhere whether it's a good or bad practice or not, but it's how I like to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely in a separate js file. Then you could reuse the logic on another similar page.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice suggests that you should place this in a separate file. Personally, I would always write this kind of validation server-side, not javascript, especially if the resulting action is a delete.

I would use javascript to allow for a "select all" feature and I would use jQuery to create an "Are you sure" prompt.